# Array to string conversion - Laravel 9 Error

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to store normal data using laravel controller, this my store() function :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate(
        [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'adress' => 'required|string',
            'cin' => 'required|string',
            'surface' => 'required|string',
            'type' => 'required|string',
        ]
    );

    if($request->type == '0'){
        return back()->with('error', 'error');
    }

    $majoration = 0;
    $amount = $this->calculateTax($request->type, (int)$request->surface);
    
    $tnb = Tnb::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'adress' => $request->adress,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'cin' => $request->cin,
        'surface' => $request->surface,
        'majoration' => $majoration,
        'amount' => $amount,
        'status' => '0',
        'datebuy' => $request->datebuy,
        'type' => $request->type,
    ]);
    
    if($tnb){
        return back()->with('success', 'success');
    } else{
        return back()->with('error', 'error');
    }
}
```

But after submitting the form, I'm getting this error :

> Array to string conversion

at :

```
$tnb = Tnb::create([

        'name' => $request->name,

        'adress' => $request->adress,

        'phone' => $request->phone,

        'cin' => $request->cin,

        'surface' => $request->surface,

        'majoration' => $majoration,

        'amount' => $amount,

        'status' => '0',

        'datebuy' => $request->datebuy,

        /** Error here **/
        **'type' => $request->type,**

    ]);
```

This is the blade code for all the fields that i'm sending in my request, which none of them is an array:

```html
<form action="{{ route('tnb.store') }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <h6 class="text-blueGray-400 text-sm mt-3 mb-6 font-bold uppercase">
      {{ __('web.Personal Informations') }}
  </h6>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="w-full lg:w-6/12 px-4">
          <div class="relative w-full mb-3">
              <label class="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2">
                  {{ __('web.name') }}
              </label>
              <input type="text" class="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none  w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150" placeholder="{{ __('web.name') }}" name="name">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full lg:w-6/12 px-4">
          <div class="relative w-full mb-3">
              <label class="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2">
                  {{ __('web.email') }}
              </label>
              <input type="email" class="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none  w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150" placeholder="{{ __('web.email') }}" name="email">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full lg:w-6/12 px-4">
          <div class="relative w-full mb-3">
              <label class="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2">
                  {{ __('web.cin') }}
              </label>
              <input type="text" class="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none  w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150" placeholder="{{ __('web.cin') }}" name="cin">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full lg:w-6/12 px-4">
          <div class="relative w-full mb-3">
              <label class="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2">
                  {{ __('web.phone') }}
              </label>
              <input type="text" class="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none  w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150" placeholder="{{ __('web.phone') }}" name="phone">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <hr class="mt-6 border-b-1 border-blueGray-300">

  <h6 class="text-blueGray-400 text-sm mt-3 mb-6 font-bold uppercase">
      {{ __('web.Land Informations') }}
  </h6>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="w-full lg:w-12/12 px-4">
          <div class="relative w-full mb-3">
              <label class="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2">
                  {{ __('web.adresse') }}
              </label>
              <input type="text" class="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none  w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150" placeholder="{{ __('web.adresse') }}" name="adress">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full lg:w-4/12 px-4">
          <div class="relative w-full mb-3">
              <label class="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2">
                  {{ __('web.datebuy') }}
              </label>
              <input type="date" class="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none  w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150" name="datebuy">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full lg:w-4/12 px-4">
          <div class="relative w-full mb-3">
              <label class="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2">
                  {{ __('web.surface') }}
              </label>
              <input type="number" class="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none  w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150" placeholder="{{ __('web.surface') }}" name="surface">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full lg:w-4/12 px-4">
          <div class="relative w-full mb-3">
              <label class="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2">
                  {{ __('web.type') }}
              </label>

              <select class="border-0 px-8 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none  w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150" name="type">
                  <option value="0">                        {{ __('web.choose') }}             </option>
                  <option value="house">                    {{ __('web.house') }}              </option>
                  <option value="land">                     {{ __('web.land') }}               </option>
                  <option value="villa">                    {{ __('web.villa') }}              </option>
                  <option value="appartement">              {{ __('web.apartements') }}        </option>
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="w-full flex justify-center items-center p-6">
      <button class="bg-blue-500 text-white active:bg-pink-600 font-bold uppercase text-xs px-4 py-2 rounded shadow hover:shadow-md outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150 hover:scale-105 text-xl" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-save me-2"></i>
          {{ __('web.save') }}
      </button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

This is the result of dd($request):
[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSCci.png)

Comment: Please post the code as text.

Comment: Please share a var_dump of request values after validation. in validation rule add more filters like string, number etc.

Comment: most probably you are sending from form 'type' as an array, not a 'string' and in your model 'type' described as string, provide more information as asked by prev comments, and improve your validation instead of using just required use required|string|max:255

Comment: Thanks for your participation, I did the required changes as you asked

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? That's a lot of code, and you haven't shared which line causes the problem

Comment: I have shared an image of the error and where it's getting stuck. It says 'Array to string conversion' at this line in store function : 
'type' => $request->type

Comment: "I have shared an image of the error " - please don't do that. Share all details in text form, and add them to your question by editing it

Comment: @SaadEs please call `dd($request->type)` at the beginning of your controller or at least before `$tnb =...`. and let us see how `Tnb` defined.

Comment: @BagusTesa I have attached an image for the result of dd($request) at the end of my question

Comment: Please add all clarification (like the **full and exact** error message, including the line where the error happened; or any debugging output) in text form, along with your attempts to resolve the problem